# Dynamically modifying serializer fields in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, frameworks, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use the Advanced serializer usage described in the django rest framework documentation. http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#advanced-serializer-usage to dynamically modifying serializer field

Here is my serializer class:

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    moviework_work = MovieWorkSerializer(many=True) 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        dropfields = kwargs.pop('dropfields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(MovieSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if dropfields:
            # Drop fields specified in the `fields` argument.
            banished = set(dropfields)
            for field_name in banished:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('field1','field2','moviework_work')
```

Here is my viewset

```
class MovieFromInterpreterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer(dropfields=('moviework_work',))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'MovieSerializer' object is not callable
```

Comment: The link to advanced-serializer-usage above returns a 404. Here is the updated link: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#advanced-serializer-usage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that you are setting `serializer_class` not to a class, but to an instance of the class. You either need to set `dropfields` as an attribute on the class, (just like it does for `fields` in the documented example you link to) or you need to look at overriding the `get_serializer` method of the viewset ([docs](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views.html#methods)).

Comment: I understand that `serializer_class` is not a class but I can't understand this answer since that the links seems to be outdated. Can you update the links? or give an example attending to the question posted?