# Pass extra arguments to Serializer Class in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to pass some arguments to DRF Serializer class from Viewset, so for I have tried this:

```
class OneZeroSerializer(rest_serializer.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print args # show values that passed

    location = rest_serializer.SerializerMethodField('get_alternate_name')

    def get_alternate_name(self, obj):
        return ''


    class Meta:
        model = OneZero

        fields = ('id', 'location')
```

**Views**

```
class OneZeroViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

   serializer_class = OneZeroSerializer(realpart=1)
   #serializer_class = OneZeroSerializer

   queryset = OneZero.objects.all()
```

Basically I want to pass some value based on querystring from views to Serializer class and then these will be allocate to fields.

These fields are not include in Model in fact dynamically created fields.

Same case in this question [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696403/dynamically-modifying-serializer-fields-in-django-rest-framework), but I cannot understand the answer.

Can anyone help me in this case or suggest me better options.

Comment: @PauloScardine can you provide me simple example or any link where i can get help? I am new to django thats why can't getting your words.

Comment: The answer to the question you refer is right, go read the documentation on the `get_serializer` method and override it to return a custom instance of the serializer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically modifying serializer fields in Django Rest Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696403/dynamically-modifying-serializer-fields-in-django-rest-framework)

Comment: I have also mentioned this question as reference, but there is no detail that can help me

Comment: The answer to the other question tells exactly what you should do, but looks like you are not willing to read the documentation and write the solution by yourself - instead you want us to write it for you, for free. All due respect, I suggest you hire a tutor at oDesk or eLance instead.

Comment: I have read the documentation but i cannot found any example where extra parameters are passed. there are just example how to use different serialize class. that why i posted question here

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views.html#methods

Comment: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L228

Comment: There is no info about add extra parameters in both links.

Answer (score 154):

It's very easy with "context" arg for "ModelSerializer" constructor.

For example:

in view:

```
my_objects = MyModelSerializer(
    input_collection, 
    many=True, 
    context={'user_id': request.user.id}
).data
```

in serializers:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
...

    is_my_object = serializers.SerializerMethodField('_is_my_find')
...

    def _is_my_find(self, obj):
        user_id = self.context.get("user_id")
        if user_id:
            return user_id in obj.my_objects.values_list("user_id", flat=True)
        return False
...
```

so you can use "self.context" for getting extra params.

[Reference](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)

Comment: This is not working..when I pass context with extra field in my serializer this extra field is missing and context looks like: `{'request': <rest_framework.request.Request object at 0x103a2ba20>, 'view': <api.views.CourseAssignmentViewSet object at 0x10326b828>, 'format': None}`

Comment: @redcyb could you help me with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039305/how-to-pass-extra-context-to-django-rest-framework-serializers

Comment: The method name should be `get_is_my_find(self, obj)`

Answer (score 52):

You could in the **YourView** override `get_serializer_context` method like that:

```
class YourView(GenericAPIView):

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context["customer_id"] = self.kwargs['customer_id']
        context["query_params"] = self.request.query_params
        return context
```

or like that:

```
class YourView(GenericAPIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        serializer.context["customer_id"] = request.user.id
        serializer.context["query_params"] = request.query_params

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        ...
```

and **anywhere** in your serializer you can get it. For example in a custom method:

```
class YourSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    def get_alternate_name(self, obj):
        customer_id = self.context["customer_id"]
        query_params = self.context["query_params"]
        ...
```

Comment: could you help me with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039305/how-to-pass-extra-context-to-django-rest-framework-serializers

Comment: @banky, I've added a comment below https://stackoverflow.com/a/62040334/6077223

Comment: Saved my day! I was looking for this for a long time

Answer (score 29):

To fulfill the answer of redcyb - consider using in your view the `get_serializer_context` method from `GenericAPIView`, like this:

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
    return {'user': self.request.user.email}
```

Comment: Just overriding `get_serializer_context` won't cut it, cause the real place, where `validated_data` is updated with context is `serializer.save()` method, which is called by `ViewSet.update() -> ViewSet.perform_update()` and `ViewSet.create() -> ViewSet.perform_create()`. But the catch is that they don't pass `**kwargs` with context to `save()`. So, in order to mix-in the context, we'll have to override `perform_create` and `perform_update` so that they pass context to `save()`.

Comment: @andilabs could you help me with this please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039305/how-to-pass-extra-context-to-django-rest-framework-serializers

Answer (score 14):

A old code I wrote, that might be helpful- done to filter nested serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    field3  = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_filtered_data')

    def get_filtered_data(self, obj):
        param_value = self.context['request'].QUERY_PARAMS.get('Param_name', None)
        if param_value is not None:
            try:
                data = Other_model.objects.get(pk_field=obj, filter_field=param_value)
            except:
                return None
            serializer = OtherSerializer(data)
            return serializer.data
        else:
            print "Error stuff"

    class Meta:
        model = Model_name
        fields = ('filed1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

How to override get_serializer_class:

```
class ViewName(generics.ListAPIView):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        param_value = self.context['request'].QUERY_PARAMS.get('Param_name', None)
        if param_value is not None:
            return Serializer1
        else:
            return Serializer2

    def get_queryset(self):
       .....
```

Hope this helps people looking for this.

Comment: exactly what I needed with getting query params, thanks! Note that the code as displayed has been deprecated. to get param values, it now looks like `self.context['request'].query_params.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

List of element if your query is a list of elements:

```py
my_data = DataSerializers(queryset_to_investigate, 
                          many=True, context={'value_to_pass': value_passed}
```

in case off single data query:

```py
my_data = DataSerializers(queryset_to_investigate, 
                          context={'value_to_pass': value_passed}
```

Then in the serializers:

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = 'Name_of_your_model'

    def on_representation(self, value):
        serialized_data = super(MySerializer, self).to_representation(value)
        value_as_passed = self.context['value_to_pass']
        # ..... do all you need ......
        return serialized_data
```

As you can see printing the self inside `on_representation` you can see: `query_set: <object (x)>, context={'value_to_pass': value_passed}`

This is a simpler way, and you can do this in any function of serializers having self in the parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the context kwargs passed to a serializer like;

```
...
self.fields['category'] = HouseCategorySerializer(read_only=True, context={"all_fields": False})
...
```

In your serializer, that is `HouseCategorySerializer` do this in one of your functions

```
def get_houses(self, instance):
    print(self._context.get('all_fields'))
```

Using `self._context.get('keyword')` solved my mess quickly, instead of using `self.get_extra_context()`

Answer (score 0):

These answers are far to complicated; If you have any sort of authentication then add this property to your serializer and call it to access the user sending the request.

class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
@property
def sent_from_user(self):
    return self.context['request'].user
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the arguments as keyword arguments when you initialize the serializer in your Viewset. For example:

```
class OneZeroViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     serializer_class = OneZeroSerializer

def list(self, request):
    some_argument = 'some value'
    serializer = self.get_serializer(context={'arg_name': some_argument}, many=True)
    return rest_response.Response(serializer.data)
```

Then, you can access the arg_name value in your serializer's **init** method by using the context.

```
class OneZeroSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         argument = kwargs.pop('context', {}).get('arg_name')
         print(argument)
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = OneZero
    fields = ('id', 'location')
```