# Django 1.8 getting kwargs in Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This seems a bit odd to me, but works for now. Since I am very new in django/python, tell me how you would solve the problem.
Goal is to create a Waypoint Object, which has a Trip id as parameter in the path. Trip is foreignkey for Waypoint.

```
class WaypointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    trip = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Waypoint
        fields = ('id', 'trip', 'position', 'time')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        trip_id = self.context.get('request').parser_context['kwargs']['pk']
        validated_data['trip'] = Trip.objects.get(pk=trip_id)
        return super(WaypointSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Comment: Why would you do this? You have a `trip` field in your serializer, so it will be in validated_data.

Comment: The endpoint is something like "/trips/5545/waypoint/" And I don't want to send the trip object additional

Comment: and of course not the id, because the path is containing it already. The only thing I want to send in the body is position and time (id will be generated on inserting the object)

Answer (score 7):

A simple way without having to modify your view is to access the view via the serializer's context:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    trip_id = self.context.get('view').kwargs.get('trip_id')
    if trip_id is None:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Must set the trip_id kwarg to use this serializer.")
    validated_data['trip'] = Trip.objects.get(pk=trip_id)
    return super(WaypointSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Answer (score 6):

In view you can override get_serializer_context method:

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
    return {"trip_id": self.kwargs['trip_id']}
```

and then in the serializer you can get it from self.context:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    trip_id = self.context["trip_id"]
    validated_data['trip'] = Trip.objects.get(pk=trip_id)
    return super(WaypointSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Comment: For more information you can check my extended answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988878/pass-extra-arguments-to-serializer-class-in-django-rest-framework/38723709#38723709