# In Django REST is there a way of setting the key in a RetrieveAPIView, rather than filtering in a ListAPIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In Django REST I have a ListAPIView, which I use to fetch records (usually just the one) based on the request user:

```
class UserPageView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserPageSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk)
```

Because I am only getting one record I was wondering if there is a way to use RetrieveAPIView instead (to achieve the same results).  Either by somehow wrapping the view and calling it with the kwargs set to the request user's pk.  Or alternatively override the primary key in the RetrieveAPIView setting it to the request user's pk?

**Update**

It is possible to use a RetrieveAPIView without a URL parameter, by overriding get_object:

```
class UserPageView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserPageSerializer
    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.request.user.pk)
```

Comment: Excuse me, what are you trying to achive? I don't understand, why would you replace ListAPIView with RetrieveAPIVeiw - list is for a collection and retrieve is for single item of collection. RetrieveAPIView would work exactly the same in terms of filters and serializers.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve one record, namely the one that corresponds with the request user.  I can achieve this using ListAPIView but I have to ignore the "list", so it is messy.  I would like to use RetrieveAPIView because it returns just one record.  The problem with that though, is that you have to pass in a pk via the URL.

Comment: That is why I was wondering if it is possible to wrap the view, calling the view in the wrapper with the pk set to the request user's pk.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I think, it might be better to just create a custom APIView than mess with nuts and bolts of stock GenericViews.

Answer (score 2):

`ListAPIView` and `DetailAPIView` are [GenericAPIViews](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py), with standard implementations of list-detail-create-update-delete [mixed-in](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py) with them. I think that for your case it is simpler just to write a custom APIView than try modifying these guys - they are tough nuts to crack and it can take a couple of weeks to understand the callgraph of DRF to be able to tweak them.

```
class UserPageView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        serializer = UserPageSerializer(data=request.data, context={"user": user})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Also see: [Pass extra arguments to Serializer Class in Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988878/pass-extra-arguments-to-serializer-class-in-django-rest-framework).