# pass url parameter to serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Suppose my url be, **POST** : `/api/v1/my-app/my-model/?myVariable=foo`

How can I pass the `myVariable` to the serializer?

```
# serializer.py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = MyModel

    def custom_validator(self):
        # how can i get the "myVariable" value here?
        pass

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        self.custom_validator()
        return attrs


# views.py
class MyViewset(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass extra arguments to Serializer Class in Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988878/pass-extra-arguments-to-serializer-class-in-django-rest-framework)

Comment: What's the problem you can't figure out? Getting the `request.GET` parameter in your custom `ModelViewSet` or passing it to your custom `ModelSerializer`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access the variable via [**`request.query_params`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params) attribute

### How it's possible through serializer ?

The **`ModelViewSet`** class passing the `request` object and `view` object to the serializer as *serializer context data*, and it's accessible in serializer in **`context`** variable

#### Method-1: Use directly the `request` object in serializer

```
# serializer.py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = MyModel

    def custom_validator(self):
        request_object = self.context['request']
        myVariable = request_object.query_params.get('myVariable')
        if myVariable is not None:
            # use "myVariable" here
            pass

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        self.custom_validator()
        return attrs
```

#### Method-2: Override the `get_serializer_context()` method

```
# serializer.py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = MyModel

    def custom_validator(self):
        myVariable = self.context['myVariable']
        #use "myVariable" here

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        self.custom_validator()
        return attrs


# views.py
class MyViewset(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context.update(
            {
                "myVariable": self.request.query_params.get('myVariable')
            }
        )
        return context
```