# Add dynamic attribute to serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to add a dynamic attribute to my serializers whenever they are called. Note that I'm talking about **an attribute**, **not a field**. Here's the idea:

- User call the API
- Viewset calls the serializer with the data
- I manage to set `self.my_key = my_dynamic_value`
- Checks and returns the serializer data (normal process)

To set my dynamic value, I need to use **`self.context`** meaning I can't override the `__init__` method of the serializers (they are called on server start and context is empty)

Any idea on how I could do it?

Comment: Why don't you instantiate the serializer in the revevant method of viewset, and add the attribute yourself there?

Comment: Reading through another topic, I found a suitable solution. I added it as an answer, but it sounds similar to what you were implying. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It's not similar actually, but it's great that you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using another topic ([Pass extra arguments to Serializer Class in Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988878/pass-extra-arguments-to-serializer-class-in-django-rest-framework)), I managed to find a suitable solution.

I simply pass my dynamic value within the `context` by overriding the `get_serializer_context` method in the **view**, like that:

```py
class MyViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context["my_key"] = my_value
        return context
```

Then in my serializer, I can get it using `self.context["my_key"]`