# DRF pass the URL parameter into serizalizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Can we pass the URL queryset parameter into serizalizer to have filitering/calculation?

here is my endpoint: `?start_date=20210312&end_date=20210317`

herer is my viewset:

```
class BrandChartsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = BrandChartsSerializer
pagination_class = BrandChartsPagination

queryset = Brand.objects.all()

def get_queryset(self):
    start_date = self.request.query_params.get('start_date',None)
    end_date = self.request.query_params.get('end_date',None)
    if start_date is None:
        raise InvalidInputError()
    if end_date is None:
        raise InvalidInputError()

    start_date_obj = datetime.strptime(start_date,'%Y%m%d')
    end_date_obj = datetime.strptime(end_date,'%Y%m%d')

    serializer = BrandChartsSerializer(start_date_obj,end_date_obj)
    queryset = Brand.objects.all()

    return queryset
```

here is my serizalizer:

```
class BrandChartsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
rankings = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
instagram = IGSerializer(allow_null=True)
facebook = FBSerializer(allow_null=True)
hashtags = BrandHashtagSerializer(allow_null=True, many=True)
# rename the json field
brand_uid = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')
brand_name = serializers.CharField(source='name')
origin = serializers.CharField(source="country")

class Meta:
    model = Brand
    fields = [
        "brand_uid",
        "brand_name",
        "origin",
        "rankings",
        "instagram",
        "facebook",
        "hashtags",
    ]

def get_rankings(self, instance):
    rank = instance.rankings.all().filter(created__gte=start_date_obj,
                                          created__lte=end_date_obj
                                          ).order_by('created')
    return BrandRankSerializer(rank, allow_null=True, many=True).data
```

and it will have `Unresolved reference 'start_date_obj'`  in `get_rankings`, however I tried to passed the parameter into serizalizer by `class BrandChartsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer,start_date_obj,end_date_obj)`

It still giving error.

Due to my function design, I think it could not use DRF filter to handle it, could I just pass the parameter to serizalizer to do filitering? (I need  to filter the rankings model in range and calculate the sum than return)

Comment: You can try this similar solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/28750126/9298143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of context in such cases.

Try this.

Update the `get_rankings` method.

```
def get_rankings(self, instance):
    start_date_obj = self.context.get("request").query_params.get("start_date")
    end_date_obj = self.context.get("request").query_params.get("end_date")
    rank = instance.rankings.all().filter(created__gte=start_date_obj,
                                          created__lte=end_date_obj
                                          ).order_by('created')
    return BrandRankSerializer(rank, allow_null=True, many=True).data
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I solved it from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28750126/9298143