# How can I get the `pk` from the endpoint while doing object level validation?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have an endpoint as `api/v1/controller/{pk}/device`

Now I want to add a device to the controller object while I am doing the object level validation by acquiring the `{pk}` of the controller object:-

```py
def validate(self, data):
    data['device'] = self.(do something to get the PK present in the endpoint)
    data.full_clean()
    return data
```

Is there any way I can get the `pk/id` from the endpoint while doing an object level validation for performing a `create` operation under the controller resource.

Comment: Is the code resides in serializer??

Comment: Yes @shourav It's present in the serializer class.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the name of serializer is `SomeSerializer`. You can pass the id through context like this.

```py
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    SomeSerializer(data=request.data, context={"instance_id": kwargs.get('pk')})
```

and get the context in `validate` method like this

```py
class SomeSerializer(serailizers.Serializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        validated_data = super(SomeSerializer, self).validate(attrs)
        instance_id = self.context.get('instance_id')
        # you can use the passed pk here
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @shourav's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68259852/10170918), if you perform update operation like `put` / `patch` on object then you can use `self.instance` in serializer's validate method. For example;

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer


class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):        
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs=attrs)
        if self.instance:
            pk_value = self.instance.id
        ...
        return attrs
```

from the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#accessing-the-initial-data-and-instance);

> When passing an initial object or queryset to a serializer instance, the object will be made available as .instance. If no initial object is passed then the .instance attribute will be None.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer from here:- [Pass extra arguments to Serializer Class in Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988878/pass-extra-arguments-to-serializer-class-in-django-rest-framework)

This is what I Did:-

```
class SomeView(ListCreateAPIView):
...
...
...
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context['device_id'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        return context

class SomeSerialzier(serializers.ModeSerializer):
...
...
...
    def validate(self, data):
        data['device'] = self.context['device_id']
        data.full_clean()
        return data
```